# Taking a comma separated list and creating a unordered list

Tags: jquery

I've got a simple list which is generated by a checkbox list. The generated code is simply this

```
white,blue,red,black
```

I need to use jquery to wrap each of these elements in a < li > tag. How do you go through the list and use the comma as a separator? I also will need to delete the comma. Sometime there will be 1 item, sometimes 3, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mystring = 'white,blue,red,black';
    mystring = '<ul><li>' + mystring.replace(/,/gi,'</li><li>') + '</li></ul>';
    document.write(mystring);
</script>
```

Outputs:

```
<ul>
<li>white</li>
<li>blue</li>
<li>red</li>
<li>black</li>
</ul>
```

This doesn't use jquery at all :)

Comment: What does the "gi" in the string accomplish. Sorry if it's a stupid question. I'm pretty new to javascript.

Comment: @mmsa g is for "global", without it you would only replace the first comma. i is for "case insensitive", this is optional in your method as there are no uppercase commas.

Answer (score 4):

```
var el = $('#elementSelector');
var values = el.html().split(',');
el.html('<ul>' + $.map(values, function(v) { 
  return '<li>' + v + '</li>';
}).join('') + '</ul>');
```

Comment: @wombleton +1 for not using `String#split()` instead of regex

Answer (score 1):

lol, 1 character shorter than `omfgroflmao` :D and no jquery goodiness

```
mystring = '<ul>' + mystring.replace(/(\w+),?/g, '<li>$1</li>') + '</ul>';
```

with jquery goodiness 1 more character shortened.. haha

```
myobject = $('<ul>').append(mystring.replace(/(\w+),?/g, '<li>$1</li>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var final_string = "<ul><li>" + myString.replace(/,/gi, '</li><li>') + "</li></ul>";
```